# Shopware 6 - The HOME or COMPOSER_HOME environment variable must be set for composer to run correctly

Tags: composer-php, shopware, shopware6

i just wanted to install the newest Shopware version 6.4.16.1 and i get this failure:

`The HOME or COMPOSER_HOME environment variable must be set for composer to run correctly`

i have composer installed and the home and composer_home variables are available on the server. what am i doing wrong? i have never got any error like that

Answer (score 2):

This is indeed a known issue, which was fixed in the upcoming v6.4.17.0 release, see the [official ticket](https://issues.shopware.com/issues/NEXT-23532).

A workaround for now would be to add a `.env` in the root directory with following content:

```
COMPOSER_HOME="/var/cache/composer"
```

If you already have a `.env` there just add that line.

Comment: I just installed 6.5.0.0 on an Ubuntu 22.04 VM and got the same issue